# Wrong library columns assigned with content type

Tags: sharepoint

I have several content types assigned to a document library. After I did a small change to one of the content types, I deleted all content types and all columns from the (empty) library and re-assigned the modified content types. Now several of the library columns are wrong: Somehow the column links in the library settings page reference the wrong columns, something like column A points to column B (but with the name A), etc. Within the content type the column references are correct, also the site columns are correct.

Emptying the recycle bins does not help, even deleting and re-creating the complete site collection does not help. The same wrong references re-appear. The document library is in a subite of the site collection.

What can be reason for this strange behaviour.

Comment: The content types are derived from Document Set: DS -> CT1 -> CT2.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created site column and content type manually then please ensure below steps:-
1.  If A pointing to B, please check one column above column A, this generally happen when one column does not exist in site column xml but referring in content type XML.
2.  Also check whether column A and column B also exist in site column xml or not. 
3.  Check the GUID of the site columns they should be different.

Comment: That was a very helpful hint, thank you. The problem was that I commented out a column definition in the Elements.xml file, but forgot to delete the corresponding <FieldRef> element in the content type definition. This did not result in an error message, but SharePoint silently created a dummy field for the pending <FieldRef>. So, the columns in the content type and also in the site collection and subsite seemed OK, only when assigning the content type to a document library, this resulted in corrupted library fields, as described in my question.